# DevXpress.XtraEditors v11.1 assembly or file not found error c#

Tags: c#, devexpress

[image]

Hello Everyone,

I am getting the error as shown in the picture above.It says DevXpress.XtraEditors v11.1 not found.I was getting this error when I tried executing my application on other machines.I don't know why I am getting this error.I haven't used DevXpress Controls anywhere in my application.If I remove DevXpress references I get more errors when I haven't used DevXpress anywhere.Can anyone help me get rid of this error.

Thanks

Comment: "I haven't used DevXpress Controls anywhere in my application." Well, then you must be using something that uses them. Try running dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ or something like .Net Reflector or ILSpy to find out what is referencing the DevExpress modules.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your application can't find the DevExpress 11.1 class libraries (DLL files) on the machines you're deploying to.

The reason it works on your development machine and not on the target deployment machines is because the DevExpress installation registers the DLL's with the .Net GAC - Global Assembly Cache.

Somewhere your project must be referencing and using a control from the XtraEditors suite. Double check your project references to be sure, it might also be worth doing a find all files operation on your project and see if any of your classes are using the XtraEditors namespace.

If you hadn't referenced and used one of the XtraEditor controls you wouldn't get this issue. You might find that DevExpress itself inserted a control upon project creation, or perhaps you accidentally used one.

For future reference, under your references if you do need to include the DLL with your project you can expand your references and choose to copy to local = true .

Comment: "Somewhere your project must be referencing and using a control from the XtraEditors suite" - I would even say where it is exactly. It is in the Lead_Management_Pro.FrmRegistration. This form either contains a DevExpress component or a component that inherits from a DevExpress component or uses it.

Answer (score 1):

1) remove all reference of devexpress from your project.

2) go to properties folder of your project remove licenses.licx

3) Clean your solution and build

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Lane Thank you very much.I finally solved the error.Actually the mistake was mine,after scrutinizing the project I found out that I had used DevXpress label control on a form.I replaced them removed all the references and the code worked fine

@Pramod Maurya You're solution also helped me.I removed lic file

Comment: Good to know you've got it working. Also I see your account is new so, welcome to stackoverflow! Enjoy your time here.